# How to add transparency to a PNG image with ImageMagick

Tags: icons, imagemagick, transparency, alpha, imagemagick-convert

**How to add transparency to a PNG image using ImageMagick?**
**How to reduce PNG file opacity using ImageMagick?**
**How to modify a PNG's alpha channel using ImageMagick?**

Use case:
You have several PNG images like this (Source opacity: 100%)
[image: Source image]

And what to increase their transparency like this (Target opacity: 70%)
[image: Wished result]

Using ImageMagick's `convert` command, allowing to script and process hundreds of icons at a time.

(Note: Background pattern is only used to highlight transparency)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use one of the following command:

```
$ convert input.png -matte -channel A +level 0,70% +channel output.png
```

This command will add 30% transparency (decrease opacity from 100% to 70%)

[Source](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=19673#p77512)

Comment: "add 30% transparency" - does that mean if it's already 50% transparent, it will become 80% transparent? How do you simply set the alpha channel to a hard number?

Comment: @minseong I don't know/remember, that was 8 years ago :) I was coming from 100% opacity anyway so it did not matter. Try it and tell us!